# Java : How to end 'do while'' loop after last run

Tags: java, do-while

How do I change my code so the last print out is empty print instead of '+'?

Based on the given number of x in `runLoop(x)`, the code prints out '+' in a row.

For example `runLoop(5)` prints `'+++++'`, after this I want to get an empty print, but I end up with "+".

EDIT: I think it is because the program runs 'do' before it checks 'while'. First the program runs runLoop(5), so it expects the output to be ''+++++'', the second time it runs runLoop(0) so the program expects to recieve a blank line, instead it gets ''+''. What I'm trying to do is to get the blank line instead of '+'.

```
public static void runLoop(int x){

    do {
        System.out.print("+");
        x--;

    }while ( x > 0);
        System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'empty print'?

Comment: How will you see `""`?

Comment: You can stop a loop with the `break` keyword. If that is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think its good do while problem

```java
public static void runLoop(int x){
    string token = ""
    do {
        System.out.print(token);
        x--;
        token = "+"
    }while ( x >= 0);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

```java
public static void runLoop(int x){
    if(x < 1){
       System.out.println("");
       return;
    }
    do {
        System.out.print("+");
        x--;
    }while ( x > 0);
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question. But if you want the last output to be different, just make the while to be `x=>0` and print something after

```
public static void runLoop(int x){

    do {
        System.out.print("+");
        x--;

    }while ( x >= 0);
        System.out.println("");
   //you can print what you need after the while loop  
   //System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: I tried, did not work.  I think it is because the program runs 'do' before it checks 'while'. First the program runs runLoop(5), so it expects the output to be ''+++++'', the second time it runs runLoop(0) so the program expects to recieve a blank line, instead it gets ''+''. What I'm trying to do is to get the blank line instead of '+'.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to replicate the error you describe with the code you provided. Are you sure there is no print of + outside the method?

Why not turn it around and simply print the last one with the linebreak?

```java
private static void loop(int x) {
    while ( x > 1) {
        System.out.print("+");
        x--;
    }
    System.out.println("+");
}
```

Comment: I did that in my last exercise, now they are asking for a ''do while'' loop :)